# Resizing elements relative to screen size

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

On my website i have created a menu using circular list elements. I am having trouble with them moving around on smaller screens. I haven't been able to find a way to make them resize relative to the screen size and stay on the same line. When the screen size is below a certain size they jump to other lines or all over the place.

What i would like if they would re-size relative to the screen size so they stay on one line.

Note:  This does not apply to Mobile and tablet as there i will use a different design.

The website in question is here: http://wonx.dk/pwdh2/index.html

Thanks in advance for your help :).

Comment: Show us your html and css rather than just linking to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In css you can actually create a resizable/responsive circle with text by defining the height of your circle to 0 and setting the padding-bottom to your circle's width value. Throw in a span with text and absolutely center it and you have a fully resizable circle.

As a bonus I also specified the font-size in VW units in order to have the scalable circle and text.

```
link to fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/788fLgjf/2/

.circle {
    position:relative;
    width:15%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:15%;
    background:black;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:100%;
}
.circle > span {
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    font-size:3vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think want you want is a an elastic (or) fluid layout.
If you want your elements to adjust according to the size of the browser window,then may be you should go for fluid layout instead of fixed layout.
Check these articles.

[What's The Difference Between Liquid, Elastic, Relative, Fluid, Flexible and Fixed Layouts?](http://www.thesitewizard.com/webdesign/liquid-elastic-fixed-relative-layout.shtml)

[Fixed vs. Fluid vs. Elastic Layout: What’s The Right One For You?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/)

Answer (score 0):

you should put your list in a main div:

```
#main_div{
    width:500px; height:150px; //for example
    margin:0 auto; //to center the div
}
```